# what is the air speed of an HVAC central air system return at the filter?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, airflow, hvac

I figured I would ask here before going out and buying an anemometer. for a 20" by 25" HVAC Return (or just state the size W x H that your data is based off). Assume a 3 ton system. what is the ball park expected air pressure, air speed, or CFM. with out a filter, with a new cheap filter, and if I have no filter but cover up half the opening so it becomes a 12.5" by 20" opening?

thanks

Comment: It doesn't work that way. You haven't supplied any of the relevant info, ie., the air handler specs, duct types, sizes, and lengths, etc. This requires a simple but tedious calculation of the equivalent duct length of every single little component in the system (both supply and return). Then you need to match the total pressure drop with the performance curve of the air handler. Industrial and commercial systems run very differently from residential systems. Please take the trouble to capitalize and punctuate your questions properly.

Comment: Why do you care?

Comment: @ Phil Sweet - I asked for ball park figures, I understand there is a lot of factors in play but if someone has a tool to measure the airflow at the filter, I'm interested in what measurements they get. I read that the airflow speed in vents are typically 18 to 20 mpg. is that correct? if you block half the opening does the CFM stay the same and air speed doubles?

Comment: @Carl Witthoft - do you ask that question to everyone that asks a question? we all have our reasons for asking a question. Your response is not additive.

Comment: @Exclusiveicon   I ask when the question appears to be looking for information that will not be of much use.  If you can explain what you would do with knowledge of the flow rate, we might be able to suggest alternative approaches.  In the meantime, try not to be hostile.

Answer (score 0):

"400 is the standard CFM per ton, but you can go from 350-450 and still be in a normal range." [Quote Source](http://hvac-talk.com/vbb/showthread.php?121424-CFM-per-ton-question)

for a dirty filter and blocking half the filter... "At higher static pressures the motor is using more energy to maintain airflow. Higher pressures mean higher operating speeds. "
[Quote Source](http://hvac-talk.com/vbb/showthread.php?403522-Does-a-blower-motor-with-a-dirty-filter-pull-more-or-less-than-normal-amps)

HVAC Systems vary but variable speed system will speed up to compensate for the restricted airflow to keep a constant airflow. so by blocking half the in-take the air pressure/suction will increase to keep the CFM the same.

Comment: You asked for "blocking half the opening with no filter" so you have no answered that...

Comment: @ Solar Mike - read the answer again... "....and blocking half the filter"

Comment: Your question clearly states « if I have no filter but cover up half the opening » so you need to read your question AND answer and make sure they match...